# How to use linalg.lstsq() with sparse matrix? How to save BIG sparse matrix to portable data format

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am learing python now and having one question regarding numpy.linalg.lstsq()
it always give me some error if there is a sparse matrix:
Here is a test I did

```
I = np.array([0,3,1,0])
J = np.array([0,3,1,2])
V = np.array([4,5,7,9])
A = sp.sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(4,4))
w=np.linalg.lstsq(A,B)[0]
```

In this case, I got:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-312-d63f88f92c68>", line 1, in <module>
w=np.linalg.lstsq(Atest,B)[0]

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1822, in lstsq
_assertRank2(a, b)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 196, in _assertRank2
'two-dimensional' % len(a.shape))

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
"
```

However, it can work well if I define the A as a normal array:

```
Atest=np.array([[4,0,9,0],[0,7,0,0],[0,0,5,0],[0,0,0,0]])
w=np.linalg.lstsq(Atest,B)[0]
```

Anyone can help give some suggestion to save sparse matrix to 'normal array'. I tried to use .todense(). It can work well if the sparse matrix is not so big. However, it will give me a error if the sparse matrix is very big.

```
File "<ipython-input-313-f232260bfc9f>", line 1, in <module>
tosave=bigsparsematrix[:,1:-1].toarray()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 901, in toarray
return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 269, in toarray
B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 789, in _process_toarray_args
return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)

ValueError: array is too big
```

Comment: Numpy doesn't handle scipy's sparse matrices.  Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html, or the other functions in `scipy.sparse.linalg`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html